# Create two value axis and plot line segments matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am having a hard time trying to plot some values and creating line segments between the two data points with matplotlib(new with matplotlib). So far my code looks like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datax1=[0,0,0,0,0]
datay1=[1,2,3,4,5]

datax2=[1,1,1,1,1]
datay2=[1,4,9,16,25] 

plt.plot(datax1, datay1)
plt.plot(datax2, datay2)

plot.show()
```

But so far I have been unsuccessful in creating a graph that I want after tweaking. I was wondering if it would be possible to produce a graph something like this in matplotlib:

[image]

Sort of like a "before and after" kind of a graph. So you would draw a line segment from (0,5) which is the "before" point to (1,25) which is the "after" point. I tried using plt.scatterplot and it plots the points but I wasnt sure how to fix the axis and draw a line between points.

Answer (score 3):

You just have to build better what you want to graph. The plot function (x, y) requires the points x and y, and joins them with lines, for example if I write `plot([1, 3], [6, 8])` plot a line joining the point `(1, 6)` Point `(3, 8)`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

datax1=[0,0,0,0,0]
datay1=[1,2,3,4,5]

datax2=[1,1,1,1,1]
datay2=[1,4,9,16,25] 

for i in range(len(datax1)):
    x = (datax1[i], datax2[i])
    y = (datay1[i], datay2[i]) 
    plt.plot(x, y)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Oh wow! Thanks. Can you explain why we needed to rearange the data? I am probably not understanding a basic principle of matplotlib.  Also, I was curious though if it is possible to show only 0 and 1 on the x axis and not values in between?

Comment: Update my answer, if this helps you mark it as correct please